# Error '''csc'' is not recognized as an internal or external cmd,operable program or batch file'

Tags: c#

Consider:

```
class First
{
  static void Main()
  {
    System.Console.WriteLine("piyush");
  }
}
```

I first started the developer command prompt by start menu → *Optimize Programs* → *Visual Studio 2013* → *Visual Studio Tools* → *Developer command prompt*

This is shown on start:

> ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder. 
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>

The echo command is only showing the given below:

```
%VS120COMNTOOLS%
```

After a while, it is also automatically closing itself.

The result of `set VS` is:

```
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
```

Also, is there a way to compile and run the above program as it’s possible in [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) for core Java without depending on the developer command prompt?

Comment: Check your Path Environment variable.It should point to folder where csc.exe exist

Comment: Type `set vs` and tell us the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How can I find and use the latest version of CSC.exe when using Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518905/how-can-i-find-and-use-the-latest-version-of-csc-exe-when-using-visual-studio-co)*

Answer (score 1):

Your *Path* environment variable should point to below path:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\vX.X.XXX
```

Or alternatively you can browse to the below path and run *csc.exe*:

```
csc C:/Dot.Net/First.cs
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you need to ensure your `PATH` environment variable includes the path to your installed command-line tools.

However, if you installed Visual Studio, it already includes a batch command, `vcvars.bat`, that does that, and includes another batch command, `VsDevCmd.bat`, that runs that batch command and several other ones useful for command-line development. A shortcut to that command should have been installed in your Start menu under *Microsoft Visual Studio* → *Visual Studio Tools*. You should always run Visual Studio commands from that CLI window.

In response to the new version; if `set vs` shows no environment variables starting with “VS12” then either you did not run the Visual Studio 12's ([Visual Studio 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2013)) `VsDevCmd.bat` command or it is not installed. Get Properties of the Developer Command Prompt shortcut you opened and tell us the value of the Shortcut/Target field.

You should have a *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0* directory.