# How can I find and use the latest version of CSC.exe when using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, csc

I'm setting up Visual Studio Code to write and learn C#.

I'm not able to find and use the *latest* version of C# compiler with Visual Studio Code.

Enquiring enquiring my compiler version with the Visual Studio Code terminal command *csc -langversion:?* brings up the following error message:

> csc : The term 'csc' is not recognized as the name of cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

---

*My previous attempts in solving the problem*

Having searched intensely, I have found out this:

- When *using* Visual Studio, this problem doesn't even occur. Visual Studio apparently contains the necessary .NET SDK and compiler and uses it automatically.
- I should locate the *csc.exe* file and set it as an environment variable path.

The only *csc.exe* files I find are located in the directory:
*C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v x.x.xxxxx* with the latest being version being *4.0.30319*.

All the instructions I could find suggested using this folder to be set as an environment variable path.

I do that. I now try again in Visual Studio Code: *csc -langversion:?*

Now I get the following message:

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.4084.0       for C# 5
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework,
> but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the
> latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C#
> programming language, see
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240
>
> warning CS2008: No source files specified error CS1617: Invalid option
> '?' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default"

So the *csc.exe* I was referring and have set as an environment variable path is outdated. I would, however, like to get all the modern features of C# 9.

I tried again to find the latest compiler from the folder "C:\Program Files\dotnet", but I could only find a folder, "Roslyn", which, to my understanding, refers to the newest versions of *csc*. I couldn't find any *csc.exe* in these folders.

#### The solutions?

Now should I find the latest csc.exe supporting C# 9 from somewhere *(where?)* and set it up as an environmental variable path?

Or am I on the wrong track here?

Or is the only choice that I give up Visual Studio Code completely and switch to Visual Studio (I wouldn’t want to do that). But that can't be the only solution!

---

#### Background information

I am a total beginner to the world of coding.

I have installed the latest version of .NET SDK 5.0.302.

I have installed the following extensions in my Visual Studio Code instance:

- C# (MS)
- .NET Install Tool for Extension Authors (MS),
- C# XML Documentation Comments (Keisuke Kato)
- ilspy-vscode (SharpDevelop Team)
- MSBuild project tools (tintoy)
- REST Client (Huachao Mao)

Comment: Download and install the latest .NET SDK and then install the C# extension for VS Code. That should be enough.

Comment: https://www.meziantou.net/locating-msbuild-on-a-machine.htm

Comment: This question could also have been the duplicate target for the now deleted question *[Option "csc -langversion?" is not working in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71375497)*. As one of the answers to this question hints at why use of the executable `dotnet` could be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `dotnet` command in your console to build and run a .NET 5 application.

Try to install the [C# extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) in your Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thank you for answers. As I mentioned in the end, I have already installed C# extension and .NET SDKs. I did however now locate the csc.exe inside the VSC. I found it here: "\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.13\.omnisharp\1.37.12\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn" After setting it up as an environmental path, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

The crucial piece of findings:

Using statement:

> #error version

produces detailed information about the compiler in use. It returned the same version number for the compiler as if I wouldn't have defined the Roslyn folder under the .vscode as PATH in the environment variables.

Therefore I think I can safely conclude this:

- Visual Studio Code doesn't show you the current compiler with the call *csc -langversion:?* unless you add the aforementioned Roslyn folder under .vscode as a PATH on environmental variables.
- However, **it does seem that Visual Studio Code uses this particular compiler anyway**, even though it doesn't formally recognise it. So the only thing that is really important is to install the latest .NET SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked.

I went to *My Computer* → *Properties* → *Advanced System Settings* → *Environment Variables* → double clicked on "Path" → *Add new* → pasted the directory where you can find *csc.exe* and clicked OK.

I restarted Visual Studio Code and it worked. The directory where I found *csc.exe* for me was:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.10-rel-29722-00\tools\csc